# How to map sub site requests to the parent site?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, iis, web-config

We've got one monolithic ASP.NET application at, say, *https://my-site.com*.
Inside it there is a number of controllers at path */api*, say,

*https://my-site.com/api/user*

*https://my-site.com/api/order*

*https://my-site.com/api/cart*

Now we're trying to split the monolith into separate services. These services are separate .NET Core applications. And they are going to gradually replace all those controllers in the */api* path. So while some controllers in the monolith should still be working, we need to add separate applications to handle requests for, say, *https://my-site.com/api/user*.

The site is hosted in IIS. If we create a sub application ***api*** for the https://my-site.com site , IIS starts mapping all requests to **/api/whatever** to the **api** sub application and not to the parent site. How can we make IIS map requests only for paths really present in the **api** sub application while mapping others to the parent monolith?

What we've tried so far...In *web.config* of the monolith in *system.webServer* we added an entry to the *handlers* section like this:

```
<add name="api-order" verb="*" path="api/order*" type="Monolith.Controllers.Api.Order" preCondition="managedHandler"/>
```

With this we wanted to make IIS map **/api/order** requests to the monolith and thus ignore the existing **api** sub application.

However it turns out that IIS chooses the sub application at first and checks its *web.config* already after that.

So is there any way to cheat IIS and make it map only certain requests to the **api** sub application?

Comment: what if you deploy the application on api/order and not only api ? This way, calls to api/user would still go to the monolith controller ?

Comment: Requests to /api/user come to the user sub-application of the api. Requests to /api/order come to the api sub application and get 404 Not Found response.

Comment: maybe is it looking at controllers answering to `https://example.com/api/` + controller path ? Try to remove the `api` from one controller path definition. If the controller used to match `api/order/new` it should now match `order/new` only since API is already route by IIS.

Comment: You misunderstood my question. Under api sub application there is only user service, which sucessfully processes requests to /api/user. But there is no order service, there is no order sub application. Requests to /api/order must be processed in the monolith. But they instead are mapped by IIS to the api sub application. And we need a way to make IIS map these requests to monolith.

Comment: I understood alright, it seems to me that you wrote : " If we create a sub application api for the https://my-site.com site" I merely ask what about doing " If we create a sub application api**/user** for the https://my-site.com site"

Comment: Like poutrathor said, you'll need to create your application under the subfolders of API and not directly on API. This mean their home will be the sub-folder.

Comment: You might have to do this on the load balancer instead. Put your sub-application on different servers than your monolith and create the mappings on the load balancer to send the requests to the right servers based on the URL path.

Comment: @howcheng thanks. That could solve the problem. However we would like to try to search for solutions with IIS. If any at all...(((